# Making title available on google books

Tags: c#, google-books

Does anyone know if you can programatically upload books onto google books?  Is there an API that allows you to upload?

We have registered as a publisher so we can maunally upload the books but we are expecting a large volume of books to flow through our system and are looking to automate the upload process.

I can't seem to find any help on how do it on the google books site.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the API is only available to searching books, not for uploading books. For more info take a look at:

http://code.google.com/apis/books/   and
http://booksearch.blogspot.com/2011/05/new-books-api-for-developers.html

Comment: +1 That's the impression I got too.  Thanks for confirming it though.